# Does `bazel fetch` support exclusion of targets?

Tags: bazel

Does `bazel fetch` support the exclusion of some targets, e. g.

```
bazel fetch -- //... -//some/target/...
```

...?

Unfortunately, it seems not to work:

```
ERROR: syntax error at '- //some/target/...'
```

For `bazel build` the exclusion of target using the "minus operator" (`-`) seems to work.